# How do I fail the Gitlab CI process when some of the Pytest cases fail?

Tags: pytest, gitlab-ci

I am running a Pytest framework using gitlab-ci.yml

```
- python -m pytest -rP test_basic || exit $?
```

I would like it to fail when there is an error or some of the test cases failed; I thought using exit might do the trick but it does not.
**Has anyone ever implemented it before??**

Below is the screenshot of the job
[gitlab ci status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNN2N.jpg)

Comment: Just remove the `|| exit $?` and it should work as intended.

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: @sytech so I actually dod that before. it fails but then it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `|| exit $?` this part as Pytest will give an exit code if any test case fails.

However, You can use Pytest exit codes to manipulate the pipeline.

Refer the Doc : https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/exit-codes.html